# rosbag, unable to create a map

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have another problem that need your help,

I built a data.bag using rosbag

terminal 1: turn on rosaria

terminal 2: using keyboard to drive a robot

terminal 3: turn on hokuyo_scan

terminal 4: turn on tf between hokuyo_scan and base_link

terminal 5: rosparam use_sim_time true

termial 6: rosbag record -O data.bag /scan /tf

, but when i use rosrun gmapping slam.. and rosbag play and rosrun map_sever map_saver. I do not create a map.

Please, show me how can i fix it.

Thanks you advance in your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249894/rosbag,-unable-to-create-a-map/) by [ThiemPHAM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28524/thiempham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-12**:
Replace data.bag with just file name

**Comment by [ThiemPHAM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28524/thiempham/) on 2016-12-12**:
it is not a main problem, i change data.bag to data , but i still meet the same situation above

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-13**:
Can you update your question by pasting the terminal outputs after running each commands, so that it will be easy to trace the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your rosbag record command seems wrong. Your command should be like this

> rosbag record -O data /scan /tf

Then try creating a map.

---

Originally posted by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) with karma: 243 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0